# Process and thread CPU usage in Linux top

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, cpu-usage, linuxthreads

We just discovered the peculiar feature of the Linux "top" tool.

The feature is that the summary cpu time for all threads is **less** than the time displayed for entire process. This is observed when our application spawns more than 50 threads and works for several minutes.

So the question is: what is that extra time consumed not by any thread but by the process itself? How is that possible?

As I understand the information about processes and threads CPU usage is taken from `/proc/<pid>/stat` & `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat` files. Who fills these files and why the time in `<pid>/stat` is not a sum of all `<tid>/stat` times?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't consumed by a thread that terminated?

Comment: Time spent in kernel state/threads counted in process time but not process-specific thread time?

Comment: We will doublecheck, but we already almost sure that our application starts all threads during the startup procedure and finishes them only at shutdown.